# MAMP show server logging in Terminal

Tags: terminal, logging, mamp

I'd like to be able to watch the server log in Terminal when using MAMP in OSX. Does anyone have any pointers how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Terminal:

```
tail -f <your log file>
```

Also consider just opening the log in Console.app.